# How to override the default JAXB version via Maven?

Tags: java, xml, maven, xml-parsing, jaxb

I'm working on a project which requires the latest JAXB. I am using Java JDK 1.8 included as an external library.

Apparently, JAXB (xml.bind) is bundled with this JDK (under an application called resources.jar) rather than in my pom.xml for my project. First of all, I don't know what version is actually included in the JDK - how can I confirm this?

Secondly, I would like to have a guarantee that when I add a dependency in my Maven for the latest JAXB in my pom.xml, the older version is not used. How can I have this guarantee?

I am using IntelliJ IDEA if it is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Maven is a build tool and as such you can't change or choose the runtime implementation with maven. Maven uses dependencies found in pom.xml to *compile* the project. In *runtime* classes are selected by the java `classloader`.

To override the default jaxb implementation, you need to implement a custom classloader or configure a your runtime classloader mode to "parent  last". The default is "parent first", which prefers JDK classes over everything else.

How to do this depends on your runtime environment. For example, IBM Websphere AS has an option in the admin console to select the classloader mode.

A good article on classloaders and how to implement a custom classloader: https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders

Code snippet to get the details in runtime:

```
/**
 * Usage: ClassDetails.print(JAXB.class);
 */
public class ClassDetails {

    public static void print(Class<?> clazz) {

        String apiDetails = String.format("%s - %s (%s)",
                clazz.getPackage().getSpecificationTitle(),
                clazz.getPackage().getSpecificationVendor(),
                clazz.getPackage().getSpecificationVersion());

        String implDetails = String.format("%s - %s (%s)",
                clazz.getPackage().getImplementationTitle(),
                clazz.getPackage().getImplementationVendor(),
                clazz.getPackage().getImplementationVersion());

        String classloader = clazz.getClassLoader() != null ?
                clazz.getClassLoader().toString() : "bootstrap";

        println("Class name", clazz.getCanonicalName());
        println("API details", apiDetails);
        println("Implementation", implDetails);
        println("Classloader", classloader);
    }

    private static void println(String label, String value) {
        System.out.println(String.format("%-16s: %s", label, value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any idea how I can configure the class loader (at least its mode) without any programming? I am running a jar application locally.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. Best of my knowledge it can't be done. I think your three requirements are too much to ask for and you just have to pick two: Java 8 / latest JAXB / no extra code